# Test Paypal button in React (jasmine & enzyme)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, jestjs, enzyme

I am using paypal button in my component. here it is.

```
export const PayPalSecureMessage = (props: TProps) => {

  const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });

  const createOrder = async (data, actions) => {};

  const onAuthorize = async (data, actions) => {};


  return (
    <>
      <PayPalButton
          env="sandbox"
          commit={false}
          tagline={false}
          funding={{ disallowed: [paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT] }}
          createOrder={createOrder}
          onApprove={onAuthorize}
          client={{
             sandbox:
             "ASmWKJfGIEy34343423333wrfrgfhthfgvgdfbvfg"    
          }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

I am finding it difficul to test this line of code in above component.

```
const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });
```

Here is a basic test case where i am just matching the snapshot.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { PayPalSecureMessage } from "./paypal-secure-message";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

describe("should render component", () => {

  it("should render component correctly", () => {
    const tree = shallow(<PayPalSecureMessage />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

When i run this test case, i get this error...Can someone help me how to mock this.

`ReferenceError: paypal is not defined`

Ps- 
This is the script which i am running in order for paypal to work
https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js

I am not sure how to load this script and ensure payal button is recognizable in my component test.

Comment: You might not want to be loading live scripts for unit testing *your* components, and you also certainly don't want to be unit testing 3rd-party code. If it was me and my code I'd simply create a `paypal` object in scope of the test, to render a simple html button (or simple react component), or mock that module (i.e. jest.mock with mockImplementation).

At the end of the day you probably don't care what the "snapshot" of that paypal button actually is (and because Paypal can change it pretty much at will) this will lead to less brittle unit test code for you.

Comment: @Drew Reese- thank you, i understood wat u mean. Can you pls tell me how to mock in this case ?

Comment: also looking for an answer to this. did you manage to find a solution?